# Taking the non-relativistic limit of the Dirac Lagrangian

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, schroedinger-equation, dirac-equation

I know the usual derivation (as well as the Foldy–Wouthuysen derivation) to obtain Schrödinger equation from the Dirac equation. See for example [U Alberta Phys 512](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Egingrich/courses/phys512/node46.html). But it it possible to go from
$$i\hbar c \overline{\Psi}\gamma_\mu \partial_\mu  \Psi-mc^2\overline\Psi\Psi$$
to
$$i\hbar \partial_t \psi=\frac{\hbar}{2m} \partial_i \psi\partial_i \psi^* \,?$$

where $$\Psi=(\psi,\chi)$$ or something similar. That is, getting the Schrödinger's Lagrangian from Dirac's Lagrangian? (an example without EM fields would suffice).

Comment: Of course it is possible; when you said that you know the usual derivation, did they not already cover this particular transition?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I just added a particular link of what I am talking about. Is there an easier way do such with the Lagrangian density instead?

Comment: Ah, you are trying to transform at the Lagrangian density level. I have never seen anybody present such a method; surely someone else thought of doing this, so that the lack of presentation might be a hint that it is either rather ugly or cannot be done in general.